# read a text file android

Tags: android, text-files, fileinputstream, datainputstream

I am trying to make the computer read a text file full of words and add it to an ArrayList. I made it work on a regular Java application, but can't get it to work on Android. Can someone help me out?

```
try {
   FileInputStream textfl = (FileInputStream) getAssets().open("test.txt");
   DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(textfl);
   BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String strLine;

        while ((strLine = r.readLine()) != null) {
            tots.add(strLine);  //tots is the array list
           }  
     } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I keep getting a error. The text file is 587kb, so could that be a problem?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Edit your question to include this!

Comment: How do you want it to be displayed? In a ListView so that each item is clickable? Or in a TextView?

Comment: I just want it added to a array list and then from there it is going to be added in a list to a text view. it says error on line 38 which is  FileInputStream textfl = (FileInputStream) getAssets().open("test.txt");
03-13 00:22:02.150: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at steve.fina.androidsm.FinalActivity.onCreate(FinalActivity.java:38)
-thx btw for the responces

Comment: i use to have FileInputStream textfl =new FileInputStream("test.txt");
but when i printed the size of the array list it was 0. i posted a question and someone told me to change it to 
FileInputStream textfl = (FileInputStream) getAssets().open("test.txt");
the first way worked in as regular java gui

Comment: @stevenminkus please add the entire exception stacktrace to a code block in your original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
private static String readTextFile(String fileName)
{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try
    {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(fileName)));
        String line;
        final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            buffer.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        return "";
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // ignore //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where should i located the txt files??

Comment: in the assets folder of the android application